# Modifying collection that was used in #cycle enumerator

Tags: ruby

[Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) says

> #cycle saves elements in an internal array so changes to enum after the first pass have no effect.

But I get the following:

```
a = [1]; x = a.cycle
x.next #=> 1
x.next #=> 1

a << 2
x.next #=> 2
x.next #=> 1

a = [1]; a.cycle { |x| puts x; a << x + 1; sleep 1 }
1
2
3
```

I think, according to the docs, `2` should never appear. Am I missunderstanding something, is this a bug/feature or outdated docs?

**Upd:**
The case with modifying after first pass

```
a = [1]; passed = 0; a.cycle { |x| puts x; if passed > 2; a << x + 1; else; passed += 1; end; sleep 1 }
1
1
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: Is `sleep` relevant to the question here?

Comment: Nope. But it can be useful if someone will try the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I saw that `Array` included `Enumerable`, read docs for `Enumerable#cycle` and found inconsistency. But indeed `Array` implements its own `#cycle` method, and there is nothing about `... so changes to enum after the first pass have no effect`.

So docs are OK. Array's `#cycle` is implemented that it's *internal array* is the array itself. But enumerator (or any `Enumerable` implementation) will create internal array and collect values yielded by `#next` into it until enumerator ends. Then `#cycle` continue iterating over this internal array, which can not be modified from ruby:

```
a = [1]; e = a.to_enum; c = e.cycle
# => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1]:each>:cycle> 
c.next
# => 1

# Here e haven't reached its end yet, so any change is still applied
e.one?
# => true 
a << 2
# => [1, 2] 
c.next
# => 2 

# after next operation e will be finished...
c.next
# => 1
e.one?
# => false  

# ... and now any changes ...
a << 3
# => [1, 2, 3] 
c.next
# => 2 

# ... will not give any effect
c.next
# => 1
```